# Reuse hibernate ressources from JavaSE project in web project

Tags: hibernate, jsp, tomcat, jpa, servlets

We implemented a Java SE program using JavaFX as a frontend and JPA/Hibernate with Microsoft SQL Server as backend. Our model is autogenerated from database. 
We now want to build a web interface on JSP using the same technologies and access methods without configuring Hibernate again in the new project.

The database access happens with service classes using a DAO interface. The access methods look somewhat like this:

```
public Address findAddressById(AddressPK id) {
    Address address = null;
    EntityManager em = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        address = (Address) addressDAO.findByID(em, Address.class, id);

        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return address;
}
```

We added the Hibernate / JavaFx project to the new web project and tried to access the same methods. Everything looks fine but when executing the web project we get the following exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [ssad.dsds.mobile.LoginServlet] in context with path [/ssad] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sop.lba.relaunch.utility.search.MainSearchResult
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at sop.lba.mobile.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:37)
    ...
```

How can we solve this problem? Is it generally possible to reuse methods from a Java SE Hibernate project in a Tomcat JSP project?